# Create 3D model of pile with points with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im developing an web-app that is supposed to create a 3d model of a gravel pile
from points measured with a laser instrument with three.js. The only problem is the
creating a hull that supposed to be the surface of the pile that includes all points. I already made a pointswarm model with the points and tried to make a hull around it with ConvexBufferGeometry but not all points get included in the hull when using ConvexBufferGeometry. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/). `ConvexBufferGeometry ` uses a Quick Hull implementation in order to compute the convex hull for a given set of points. If this is not the case for your data, you have to provide more information so it's possible to investigate the issue.

Comment: I can post a sample tomorrow when i am back at work but the problem is just  that convexGeometry uses quickhull and quickhull creates the smallest geometry that swallows all points but all points are part of the hull.

Comment: Have a look at this [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-delaunator/4952?u=prisoner849). If it's what you're looking for, I can post it here as an answer.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks =D that was exactly what i was looking for. Post it as a answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @Pei-turn You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to combine `Three.js` with `Delaunator` library for triangulation of your points to make a surface:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(150);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
var canvas = renderer.domElement;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
light.position.setScalar(100);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var size = { x: 200, y: 200 };
var pointsCount = 1000;
var points3d = [];
for (let i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
  let x = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(size.x);
  let z = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(size.y);
  let y = noise.perlin2(x / size.x * 5, z / size.y * 5) * 50;
  points3d.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
}

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points3d);
var cloud = new THREE.Points(
  geom,
  new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: 0x99ccff, size: 2 })
);
scene.add(cloud);

// triangulate by [x, z]
var indexDelaunay = Delaunator.from(
  points3d.map(v => {
    return [v.x, v.z];
  })
);

var meshIndex = []; // delaunay index => three.js index
for (let i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i++){
  meshIndex.push(indexDelaunay.triangles[i]);
}

geom.setIndex(meshIndex); // add three.js index to the existing geometry
geom.computeVertexNormals();
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  geom, // re-use the existing geometry
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: "purple", wireframe: true })
);
scene.add(mesh);

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(mesh.material, "wireframe");

render();

function resize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}

function render() {
  if (resize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display; block;
}

#info{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a{
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<!-- https://github.com/mapbox/delaunator -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/delaunator@3.0.2/delaunator.js"></script>

<script src="https://josephg.github.io/noisejs/perlin.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.3/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<div id="info">
   <a href="https://github.com/mapbox/delaunator" target="blank">Delaunator<br>(triangulation)</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Would you mind explaining or adding more comments in the js to explain why triangulating by X and Z works (as opposed to say Y and Z?), and also the index exchange between three and delaunator? The code definitely works but I’m having some trouble understanding why.

Comment: @mpianka We need triangulation of projections of vertices on the horizontal plane, so that's why we use x and z. Triangulator returns triplets of indices of vertices (kind of description of triangles by indices), thus we can use it in a geometry to form a mesh.